# Algorithm to maximize dot product between two sets of vectors

Tags: algorithms

I have two sets of vectors $(\mathbf{l}_i)_{1\le i \le n}$ and $(\mathbf{r}_i)_{1 \le i \le n}$. Each vector $\mathbf{l}_i$ is in $[0,1]^4$, same for $\mathbf{r}_j$. I'd like to maximize the dot product $\mathbf{l}_i \cdot \mathbf{r}_j$, i.e. find tuples $(i,j)$ s.t. $\mathbf{l}_i \cdot \mathbf{r}_j$ is as big as possible.

---

To be clear, if $\mathbf{l}_i=(\mathbf{l}_{i,1},\mathbf{l}_{i,2},\mathbf{l}_{i,3},\mathbf{l}_{i,4})$ and $\mathbf{r}_{j}=(\mathbf{r}_{j,1},\mathbf{r}_{j,2},\mathbf{r}_{j,3},\mathbf{r}_{j,4})$, then:

$$\mathbf{l}_i \cdot \mathbf{r}_j=\sum_{k=1}^4 \mathbf{l}_{i,k} \mathbf{r}_{j,k}$$

---

- The number of tuples I'd like to find should be ideally a parameter of the algorithm, i.e. find the $K$ tuples $(i,j)$ that lead to the greatest values of $\mathbf{l}_i \cdot \mathbf{r}_j$. I won't mention $K$ in the complexities below, let's say $K \ll n$.
- I'm looking for $O(n \log^k n)$ ideas. The naive algorithm takes $\Theta(n^2)$ time, which is too big for me ($n \approx 2^{20}$).
- My first idea was to try to solve the problem in dimension 2, with the additional constraint on the input $|\mathbf{r}_j|=1$. In that case it is easy to design a $O(n \log n)$ algorithm: sort all $\mathbf{r}_j$ according to their angle with $(1,0)$, then for all $i$, find $\mathbf{l}_i$ in that list by binary search.

---

In my opinion, intermediary tasks might be:

- Try to generalize the formula $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}=|\mathbf{u}| |\mathbf{v}| \cos(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})$ to dimension $4$.
- Try to remove the condition $|\mathbf{r}_j|=1$ from the algorithm in dimension $2$.

I have no idea on how to solve these two problems.

I'm asking this in a single question because I'm also interested in more general algorithms that may give approximations (e.g. that solve the "maximum dot product" problem in arbitrary dimension).

Comment: Have you read this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.6101.pdf ? Their problem is to find the max inner product for only one vector, but the authors seem to suggest that the problem is hard.

Comment: @WhatsUp: No, I didn't even know that the version with online queries of the problem had an official name ("MIPS"). Thank you! I skimmed through the litterature about it.

Answer (score 5):

As a completely different approach, assuming that $d < \log n$, one can generate $O(\log n)$ random vectors $w_i$ with unit norm. For each $w_i$ we look at $\langle l_i, w_i \rangle$ and $\langle r_i, w_i \rangle$. Take the top largest $O(\sqrt n)$ from each list, as potential candidates. After completing we have $O(\sqrt n \log n)$ candidates, and then we check the dot products between the pairs. It is important that $d < \log n$ so that $O(\log n)$ vectors are sufficient to cover the unit sphere well. In your case where $d = 4$ it would seem to be that $d << \log n$.

Comment: Interesting approach!  Can you justify why this will find the correct (optimal) solution, with high probability?  Is there a proof of correctness for this?  And why are $O( \log n)$ vectors enough?

Comment: Actually, the main point here is $d$. The density for the angle (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246748/distribution-of-an-angle-between-a-random-and-fixed-unit-length-n-vectors) is $~sin^{d-2} \theta$. So in order to have that $\theta \leq t = \arccos(r)$, the probability of a single random vector is then $p = \int_0^t sin^2 x dx = t/2 - sin(2t)/4 \approx t^3/3$. One then needs $\frac{\ln \delta}{\ln 1-p}$ random vectors, to succeed with probability $1 - \delta$. Thus, for r=0.99 (i.e., the dot product will be up to 1% smaller), and $\delta=0.01$ one needs about 4927 vectors.

Comment: Sorry some rearranging: For $||w||=1$, consider that $\langle l_i, w\rangle \langle r_i, w\rangle = |l_i||r_i|\cos \beta_l \cos \beta_r$. Note that $\cos \beta_l \cos \beta_r = \cos(\beta_l \pm \beta_r) \pm \sin\beta_l \sin\beta_r $, where the $\pm$ signs are both - if $w$ passes between $l_i$ and $r_i$, otherwise they are both +. So the end result is accurate up to a value of $\pm |l_i||r_i|\sin\beta_l \sin\beta_r$. If the angle between $l_i$ and $r_i$ is small, then w.h.p. there is $w$ such that $\beta_l \approx \beta_r$ and $\sin^2 \arccos(r) = 1 - \cos^2 \arccos(r) = 1-r^2$.

Comment: Finally, if the angle between $|l_i|$ and $|r_i|$ is "large" (but their absolute values are large enough to be in the results!), there will be some vector that will pass approximately between them and we will still have that $\beta_l \approx \beta_r$ (i.e., there exists some vector which doesn't approximate them well, but is approximately between them). For this vector, the values of $\langle l_i, w\rangle and $\langle r_i, w\rangle$ will be large, so they should be identified as candidates within the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea.

Key observation:

Let $O$ be the origin in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Let $H$ be the convex hull of the set $\{O\} \cup \{l_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\}$. Then one may only consider those $l_i$ which are vertices of $H$. Same for those $r_j$.

Finding convex hulls can be done in $O(n \log n)$ time, c.f. wiki page.

The problem is then: how many vectors still remain after this procedure.

Under certain assumptions, e.g. the vectors are uniformly distributed, this reduction could be good enough to allow a brute force on the remaining vectors.

More precisely, if the vectors are uniformly distributed, then it is known [e.g. from this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5340) that the number of remaining vectors is, in average, $O((\log n)^3)$, which is quite small.

Comment: Computing a convex hull in $\mathbf{R}^4$ is $\Omega(n^2)$, right?

Comment: I was actually not familiar with the convex hull algorithms, so I just gathered information from the wiki page. From what I learnt, there are algorithms, e.g. quickhull, which are at least empirically fast enough. Since this idea is based anyhow on some assumptions of the distribution of the vectors, I wouldn't care much about the worst-case complexity ...

Answer (score 1):

In the case of unit-length vectors, this problem reduces to the problem of finding the $K$ pairs of closest points in 4-dimensional space.  There are reasonable algorithms for that.

In particular, note that

$$\|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\|^2 = \|\mathbf{u}\|^2 + \|\mathbf{v}\|^2 - 2 \; \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v},$$

where $\| \cdot \|$ is the 2-norm.  If $\|\mathbf{u}\|=\|\mathbf{v}\|=1$, then it follows that

$$\|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\|^2 = 2 - 2 \; \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v},$$

so maximizing the dot-product $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}$ is equivalent to minimizing the Euclidean distance between the two vectors, $\|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\|$.  You can use any standard data structure and algorithm for [nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) for that problem, such as a $k$-d tree.  In particular, when the dimension is fixed (as it is here), there is [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#All_nearest_neighbors) a $O(n \log n)$ algorithm to find the nearest neighbor to each point, from which we can immediately find the $K$ pairs of nearest vectors and thus read off the solution to your problem.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem.

When the vectors aren't unit-length, this trick doesn't work any longer, and I don't know how to solve your problem.  The following question on CSTheory.SE says there is a $\tilde{O}(n^{4/3})$ algorithm for the problem, but I don't know if it can be done in $O(n \log n)$ time: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/34503/5038

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The relation between $||\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}||^2$ and $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}$ is in some sense the generalization of $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}=|\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}|\cos(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})$ I was hoping. If computational geometry experts are pointing out a $\tilde{O}(n^{4/3})$ complexity, I don't expect to find a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Not guaranteed to be exact at all, but likely to work pretty well. Let $m > 1$. Perform a k-means++ clustering first (using something like a cover tree for finding the nearest centroid) with $k = O(\sqrt n)$ for each of $l$ and $r$ (where you can do up to $O(\log^{m-1} n)$ clustering iterations). Then compare all the pairwise dot products between $l$ and $r$ centroids, in order to find the top $O(\log^m n)$ clusters to consider. Then check between all the vector pairs between the clusters found. Overall complexity is then $O(n\log^m n)$, assuming that each cluster has $O(\sqrt n)$ points in it.